# Kubernetes nginx ingress + oauth2 external auth timing out

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I am attempting to protect a service's status page with an oauth2_proxy, using Azure AD as the external auth provider. Currently if I browse to the public url of the app (https://sub.domain.com/service/hangfire) I got a 504 gateway timeout, where it should be directing me to authenticate.

I had been mostly following this guide for reference: https://msazure.club/protect-kubernetes-webapps-with-azure-active-directory-aad-authentication/

If I disable the annotations that direct the authentication, I can get to the public status page without a problem. If I browse to https://sub.domain.com/oauth2, I get a prompt to authenticate with my provider, which I would expect. I am not sure where the issue lies in the ingress config but I was unable to find any similar cases to this online, stackoverflow or otherwise.

In this case, everything (oauth deployment, service, and ingress rules) lives in a 'dev' namespace except the actual ingress deployment, which lives in its own namespace. I don't suspect this makes a difference, but SSL termination is handled by a gateway outside the cluster.

oauth2 deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: oauth2-proxy
        image: quay.io/pusher/oauth2_proxy:v3.2.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args:
        - --provider=azure
        - --email-domain=domain.com
        - --upstream=http://servicename
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        - --azure-tenant=id
        - --client-id=id
        - --client-secret=number
        env:
         - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
           value: secret
        ports:
         - containerPort: 4180
           protocol : TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    app: oauth2-proxy
```

Ingress rules:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-ingress1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://sub.domain.com/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://sub.domain.com/oauth2/start?rd=$https://sub.domain.com/service/hangfire"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sub.domain.com       
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /service/hangfire
        backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 80                    
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-oauth2-proxy
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sub.domain.com      
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /oauth2
        backend:
          serviceName: oauth2-proxy
          servicePort: 4180
```

I am getting 504 errors when I browse to the url but I do not see any errors in the ingress pods.

Comment: What do you have here as `-upstream=http://servicename` exactly? I am not able to figure out what is expected here.

Comment: I have the fqdn of the ingress host. So if I was doing this ingress for google.com, I would put that in the upstream.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I figured but I couldn't get it to work. In the end for me the problem was with the cookies being passed by Azure AD being too big for Nginx to handle, causing the redirect to fail. The only real solution is to run a redis server for managing the cookies. It was fairly hard to debug this problem, so should anyone else stumble up this, have a look at: https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/issues/866

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up finding the resolution here: https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/5958

I had to use the internal service address for the auth-url, which I had not seen mentioned anywhere else.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://oauth2-proxy.development.svc.cluster.local:4180/oauth2/auth
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've been doing with my oAuth proxy for Azure AD:

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
```

And I've been using this oAuth proxy:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER
            value: azure
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_AZURE_TENANT
            value: xxx
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
            value: yyy
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
            value: zzz
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
            value: anyrandomstring
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_HTTP_ADDRESS
            value: "0.0.0.0:4180"
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_UPSTREAM
            value: "http://where_to_redirect_to:443"
        image: machinedata/oauth2_proxy:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: oauth2-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
          protocol: TCP
```

Comment: This looks almost identical to mine. Would you mind posting more of the service ingress? Unfortunately I am just getting those 504 errors at the ingress with no real errors to go on. The only thing I am uncertain about is the 'OAUTH2_PROXY_UPSTREAM', is this supposed to be an internal service endpoint or the external url?

Comment: its supposed to be wherever you redirect after auth (for me its internal service), sure it looks similar, but its not the same, so you can better try this one, because it works for me no problems

Comment: Could you maybe expand on what `http://where_to_redirect_to:443` is supposed to be exactly? I am having trouble with this. IP address of "service-ingress1" (as defined by OP in question)? ClusterIP of the Service behind the Ingress?

Comment: rise a new question, instead of asking questions in the comments

Comment: upstream can be kubernetes service endpoint

Answer (score 0):

My setup is similar to 4c74356b41's

oauth2-proxy deployment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --azure-tenant=TENANT-GUID
        - --email-domain=company.com
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        - --provider=azure
        - --upstream=file:///dev/null
        env:
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: client-id
              name: oauth2-proxy
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: client-secret
              name: oauth2-proxy
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: cookie-secret
              name: oauth2-proxy
        image: quay.io/pusher/oauth2_proxy:v3.1.0
        name: oauth2-proxy
```

oauth2-proxy service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: oauth2-proxy
  type: ClusterIP
```

oauth2-proxy ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  labels:
    app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.hostname.net
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: oauth2-proxy
          servicePort: 80
        path: /oauth2
```

oauth2-proxy configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: monitoring
data:
# Values below are fake
  client-id: AAD_CLIENT_ID
  client-secret: AAD_CLIENT_SECRET
  cookie-secret: COOKIE_SECRET
```

Application using AAD Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$request_uri
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.hostname.net
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.hostname.net
```

An additional step that needs to be done is to add the redirect URI to the AAD App registration. Navigate to your AAD App Registration in the Azure portal > Authentication > Add `https://myapp.hostname.net/oauth2/callback` to Redirect URIs > Save

Comment: Thanks for posting, your config looks very similar to mine as well. It's weird that I am getting 504 timeouts with nothing showing in the nginx logs, it's like the auth annotations are just breaking the ingress config for me. Do you have any other nginx config changes in place? AFAIK I am running a stock config, but I haven't seen any special config changes mentioned when implementing this.